# Can I use a 22 microfarad capacitor in place of a 10 microfarad capacitor?

Tags: power-supply, power, decoder, board

I have a bad 10 microfarad capacitor 400V but can not get a replacement.

Can I use 22 microfarads 400V instead?

Comment: What is the capacitor used for, e.g. is it a smoothing capacitor, an AC coupling capacitor, part of a timing circuit, or maybe something else?

Comment: @AndrewMorton 400V cap for timing?

Comment: Please show a schematic. Without we can't give a reliable/safe advise. A capacitor has more parameters than just size and voltage rating.

Comment: You shouldn't replace X1/Y2 capacitors by X2/X2 capacitors for example. You should consider the ESR... etc

Comment: Can you add a photograph of the capacitor and circuit in question

Comment: considering this is likely an aluminum e-cap, in a  general purpose DC filter, "maybe", but it is best to known where it is used.

Comment: Thanks for all your responds.Its for a decoder power supply board. so my worry was if i could use 22 uF 400v 105 degree celcius in place of a 10 uF 400v 105 degree celcius. it is an electrolytic DC capacitor.

Comment: We need a schematic or photo to determine where the capacitor is and what it is used for.

Comment: If you have two 22µF caps and you connect them in series - the series combination would have a capacitance of 11µF - pretty close to your original capacitor.  Depending on the application you may or may not need to do this.

Comment: I am voting to close this because there is insufficient context.  What is the circuit?  The value may or may not be critical.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the application...
A higher capacitance usually comes with a higher ESR (equivalent series resistance) and obvously induces a higher time constant when involved in resonant/ filtering circuit.

But by looking at the capacitance and voltage rating of your capacitor, I am assumming it is some kind of mains/power supply filtering capacitor. In this case, the +12uF difference should not cause any harm.

Be carefull to put the new one the right way around (I am pretty sure you are faced with an electrolytic capacitor, which has a polarity).

To summarize, it will most lokely work just fine.

Comment: Yeah..thanks so much. you have cleared my doubts

Comment: @fai - If this is for a tube amplifier with a tube rectifier and you add too much capacitance, you could blow the rectifier from too much inrush current.

Comment: Just saw it's for a decoder board. Probably no problem to sub the 22 µF cap.